# Enable-RemoteMailbox - Set o365 Exchange Online Hybrid for a batch of users from CSV or TXT ( PowerShell )

Tags: powershell

Currently I am using the following Syntax, to Migrate user`s and create O365 mailboxes in our organization:

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Please provide AD-USERNAME to Migrate";

Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $username -RemoteRoutingAddress($username+'@zim365.mail.onmicrosoft.com')

sleep 30

Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
```

All is working well.

But this is only , for use with a single user.
I would like to commit this actions to a list of users from csv or txt
Please help with syntax.

Your help is most appreciated !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this from a txt file:

```
(Get-Content "FILEPATH.txt") | Foreach {
  Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $_ -RemoteRoutingAddress($_+'@zim365.mail.onmicrosoft.com')
  sleep 30
  Get-RemoteMailbox $_ | Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
}
```

For a csv file like this:

```
Username,
user1,
user2,...
```

Do:

```
Import-Csv "FILEPATH.csv" | Foreach {
  Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $_.Username -RemoteRoutingAddress($_.Username+'@zim365.mail.onmicrosoft.com')
  sleep 30
  Get-RemoteMailbox $_.Username | Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
}
```

Comment: PERFECT !  Thank you very much !